# validate input field before submitting form

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate the input field 'putime' in the form because even if the 'putime' input box is empty the result is calculated and nightSurcharges is also added to the cost. So I want to validate 'putime' when it is empty otherwise the script is useless.

```
function TaxiFare() {
// calculates taxi fare based upon miles travelled
// and the hour of the day in military time (0-23).

var baseFare = 14;
var costPerMile = 7.00;
var nightSurcharge = 20.50; // 9pm to 6am, every night //its flat 20.50 and not per mile

var milesTravelled = Number(document.getElementById("miles").value) || 0;
if ((milesTravelled < 1) || (milesTravelled > 200)) {
alert ("You must enter 1 - 200 miles");
document.getElementById("miles").focus();
return false;
}

var pickupTime = Number(document.getElementById("putime").value) || 0;
if ((pickupTime < 0) || (pickupTime > 23) || (pickupTime==null)) {  // note the hours are 0-23.  There is no 24 hour, midnight is 0 hours
alert ("The time must be 0-23 hours");
document.getElementById("putime").focus();
return false;
}

var cost = baseFare + (costPerMile * milesTravelled);
// add the nightSurcharge to the cost if it is after
// 8pm or before 6am
if (pickupTime >= 21 || pickupTime < 6) {
cost += nightSurcharge;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your taxi fare is: $. "  + cost.toFixed(2);
}


And here is the Form from HTML


    <form>
Miles for Journey <input type="text" id = "miles" required><br>
Pickup Time <input type = text id = "putime" required><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate Fare" onclick="TaxiFare()">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><br><br>
<span id = "result"></span>
</form>
```

I've tried a lot but to no avail....any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about adding an event handler to the form, in the likes of `document.forms[0].submit = validateFunction;`

where validateFunction might look like this:

```
function validateFunction()
{
    var allIns = this.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(allIns.namedItem('putime').value == '')
    {
        alert('silly');
        return false;
    }
    //and other checks go here, too
}
```